# Push data in a table to another table

Tags: sql, database

I have 3 tables like the below picture. I need to push data in Conditional table when it reach the ExpireDate, the database must move to Unconditional table (all codes in SQL). How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: heard about triggers?

Comment: w3school shows me this: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp. but I dont know what about the primary key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the easiest way is to make a job that runs daily with:

```
insert into unconditional_table
select 
*
from conditional_table a
where a.expiration_date = trunc(sysdate,'dd')
```

When the condition is not met - no data will be transferred.

Comment: Thank you!!! And then how can it delete data in Conditional table after push data?

Comment: Cou can delete them by     delete * from conditional_table where       a.expiration_date = trunc(sysdate,'dd')

Answer (score 0):

You want to move records from a table to another. 
When do you want this to happen ?

You can set up a job. This job will check the dates and move the records to another table at the beginnig of every day.